# generate receipt email React

Tags: reactjs, email, smtp, nodemailer

I am building a react web app as part of a project for uni.

the idea is the client builds a project for their own clients like scaffolding etc and as the project progresses it gets updated in a table and then I am tasked with figuring out how to collect data from the table when that table changes and automatically send an email to the client as an update on the progress of their project.

I've searched youtube and google on this but I seem to be getting email forms any help or pointers in the right direction would be great so I can continue to research and then build this part of my web app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since it's for Uni, there is a free tier on https://aws.amazon.com/ses/ that might help you here.

Comment: will check it out now, thank you